# can't read environment variables in create-react-app generated app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

I used create-react-app to generate a node app.  I changed the app.js file to look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
let a = process.env.SOMETHING;
console.log(a)
function App() {
    console.log(process.env)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          { process.env.SOMETHING }
        </a>
          </header>
          <div>The value of something: ${a}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I would expect the `a` variable to reflect what I set in the environment.  When I look at the console after starting the app, it is undefined, and all I see is the dollar sign where the variable should be inserted.

I've tried setting the variable in two ways.  Firstly, I created a bash file called `setup.bash` and gave it executable permission.  It looks like this:

setup.bash

```
export SOMETHING="boom"
```

Then I changed `package.json` to this:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./setup.bash && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

When this didn't work, I tried starting the app like this:

```
SOMETHING=BOOM npm start
```

... and the environment variable remained undefined.

Can anyone see what the problem might be?

Comment: You need to add variables in ```.env`` file then you can access. More reference you can see here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

Comment: just make a .env file and write REACT_APP_SOMETHING =boom and restart the react server and use it: process.env.SOMETHING. no need to run bash file
**MAKE SURE TO PREPEND  REACT_APP_**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Create `.env.development` text file.
Then you can list variables there, but all of them **must start** with `REACT_APP_` prefix.

For example:
`REACT_APP_API_URL=https://api.url`

You can also run the `npm start` command with variables declared before it:

`REACT_APP_API_URL="https://api.url" npm start`, but again, remember about the prefix.

Read more about environment variable for create-react-app [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables).

Comment: That site is where I got the idea to set the variable along with the start command.  `SOMETHING=BOOM npm start`.  Shouldn't this work?

Comment: @DavidJ. Variables must have prefix `REACT_APP_` in the name. In other case the create-react-app tool will not fetch them.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I forgot the REACT_APP part

Comment: still doesn't work for me. Even I restarted the app

Answer (score 6):

It did not work for me after I set `REACT_APP_API_URL=https://api.url` in `.env`

Then I stop react-app, run`npm start` and it works fine for me.

Don't forget create `.env` in the root directory